# Need some advice on a java api to use for a 'presentation display board' - based on game 2d/3d tech

Tags: 2d, 3d, sprites, java

As part of the project i am working on I am looking to produce some software that works on a LCD display (think call center info boards) and displays various graphs (the bars grow etc in realtime, so incoming call stats etc etc) and flicks between various 'plug-ins'.

I asked before, and WPF was suggested, and it looks excellent.. However i really need to keep to Java (work standards).. So the question is what XNA style API is the best for this, I can see that JMonkey etc seem to provide 3d stuff, but I also need sprites etc.

For example: Think, defused 3d planet rotating in the background, while call stats are printed over the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much 3D you're really going to use will most likely be the largest factor.

**Primarily 2D:**

If your application is primarily 2D(*like 95% to really make this a viable option*) then use the [**Slick**](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) engine which is a 2D engine.  3D models will have to be done directly in openGL via [**SlickCallable**](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/opengl/SlickCallable.html).

**Primarily 3D:**

It might be a lot easier to use the [**JMonkeyEngine**](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/home/) 3 and use textured billboards if you need a lot of 3D graphics.  A lot of the expected sprite handling will needed to be coded by yourself though, although you can stay within the world of JMonkey and not have to drop to openGL.

**Unique Hybrid of 2D and 3D:**

Depending on how much interleaving of 2D and 3D technology you need it might be more beneficial to create your own hybrid engine straight from **[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/index.php)**.

A tutorial on how to build a [**2D/3D asteroid game is located here**](http://www.cokeandcode.com/asteroidstutorial)

[**Source code here**](http://www.cokeandcode.com/asteroids/)

Comment: Cheers.. I was already looking at Slick, and for the prototyping its spot on.. Very rapid prototyping.